# Add a property observer on an existing property in an iOS library class

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, overriding

In my SpriteKit game, I want to add a property observer on the `fieldBitMask` property for the `SKPhysicsBody` of my sprites. I want to be informed when the `fieldBitMask` property changes so that I can take some action.

I overrode `SKPhysicsBody` but when I tried assigning the overridden class to a sprite node like a normal `SKPhysicsBody` object I got a bunch of errors. I also thought about making an extension for SKPhysicsBody, but Apple documentation says, “Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot override existing functionality.” So it would seem that I can't override the `fieldBitMask` property this way to make it a property observer.

I know how to create a property observer in a new custom class which I create. But what is the best way to add a property observer to an existing property in a class that is part of the Apple library?

Comment: Are you sure that you need to subscribe to this property? I think that inside a good architecture you shouldn't change a value of this property. Because this property determine a type of a physics object, if you needs change the type of the object, you can create a new instance of SKPhysicsBody.

Comment: No, but I thought this was a convenient approach for my project. I have several physics fields and some sprites, and I want to periodically change which physics fields affect the sprites. Several factors can change the fields, and rather than responding to the change in multiple places in my code, I thought it would be easier to set up the `fieldBitMask` with a property observer. Then I only need to respond to field changes in `didSet` for the property observer. Since this doesn't seem to work then I will need to take the long approach.

Answer (score 3):

You can subclass `SKPhysicsBody` like that:

```
class Subclass: SKPhysicsBody {
    override var fieldBitMask: UInt32 {
        didSet {
            print(fieldBitMask)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should work, at least it does not give me any error in Swift 4 but it probably has been possible since previous versions :)

Comment: How can I initialize this so I can assign it to a sprite node? Normally you can assign a SKPhysicsBody like this `spriteNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 2)` but your subclass has no initializers. I tried adding `super.init()` to your subclass but got a bunch of errors.

Comment: Ah, didn't think about that, looks like all initialisers and functions aren't inherited, the answer of Andrew Romanov will probably be more suited to your case then !

Comment: Yup, SKPhysicsBody is a wrapper class to PKPhysicsBody, so even if you did successfully subclass it, we have no idea what is being passed around in the PhysicsEngine, so the SKPhysicsBody we get back may not be the same SKPhysicsBody that was created

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Its unfortunate that the class is open but not the initialisers

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use the [Key Value Observing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notifications/nskeyvalueobserving). You can add observer to a property changing.
You should [implement](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1416553-observevalue) `observeValue(forKeyPath:of:change:context:)` method in your observer class.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#Key-Value%20Observing) you can find Swift example ("Key-Value Observing" part).

Comment: Your third link mentions a requirement to "add the `dynamic` modifier and `@objc` attribute to any property you want to observe." This would require you to override the existing iOS class. So this approach has the same problem as Trevör Anne Denise's answer, where overriding the class does not let you assign it to a sprite node.

Comment: SKPhysicsBody is a Objective-C class, I think you can use Key Value Observing with it without modifications.

Comment: You should add dynamic and @objc attributes to Swift classes, which will used in Objective-C code.

Comment: This may not work,  SKPhysicsBody is really a wrapper class to PKPhysicsBody, a private entity that we have no access to. Some of the entities will not fire with KVO because you need to attach it to the PKPhysicsBody, which you can't

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Not sure if it's because of the reason you gave, but I couldn't get this to work. Was getting a variety of errors.