# Using Swift Combine framework for a library variable

Tags: swift

I have a variable in my custom library, which when set, should update the variable in the MainViewController.

I have gone through Property Observers and Key-Value Observing but I don't think either of those apply to my situation.

[Add a property observer on an existing property in an iOS library class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46484188/add-a-property-observer-on-an-existing-property-in-an-ios-library-class) - This doesn't work.

As @Alexander suggested, using the Combine framework could solve this issue. I went through this tutorial : https://benoitpasquier.com/first-steps-apple-combine-framework-swift/, but is there an easier way to achieve it without the extension.

```
//CustomLibClassLibrary Library

class CustomLibClass {

    public var String1 : String = ""

    func ReceivedData(data: String) {
        String1 = data
    }
}

//Application

import CustomLibClassLibrary

class MainViewController: NSViewController {

    var appString : String = ""
    @IBOutlet weak var uiLabel: NSTextView!

    func displayString {
        uiLabel.string = appString
    }

}
```

Variable 'appString' should update when 'String1' is set.

Comment: How are the objects related to each other? In the code they aren't related at all.

Comment: Is it possible to set a notification observer for something in a library?

Comment: So, the library receives data from an external device and that data needs to be updated on my application in real-time.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I'll give it a try now. Thanks!

Comment: @curiously77 I would recommending modelling this using an Observer pattern, such as that implemented in RxSwift, or Apple's new Combine. Modelling values over time is precisely what they're for

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I'm not able to access the notification from the library.

Comment: @Alexander Can you please elaborate or give me some links to follow?

Comment: @curiously77 I would recommend starting by watching the [Introducing Combine](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/722/) video from this year's WWDC. The Combine framework isn't really usable yet (it's only available on iOS 13+, macOS Catalina+, etc.), but the concepts are very applicable to RxSwift or any other reactive programming framework, and they do a good visual job of explaining them.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to inherit new class from your CustomLibClass and make kind of proxy inside

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import CustomLibClassLibrary

class CustomLibClassSuccessor: CustomLibClass, ObservableObject {
    override var String1: String {
        didSet {
            proxyString = String1
        }
    }

    @Published var proxyString: String = ""
}

class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    @ObservedObject var object = CustomLibClassSuccessor()

    private var disposables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let objectObs =
        object.$proxyString.sink { proxyString in
            print("\(proxyString)")
        }

        disposables.insert(objectObs)
    }
}
```